# Need to do a half of a christmas tree with "*"

Tags: c

The output desired from the half of Christmas tree is:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I could get a output like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

By using only cycles and conditions (arrays, can't be used), how can I get a solution like the first one?

```c
main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Introduza o número de ramos:        ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= i; j++)
        {   

            putchar('*');

        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously understand how to put a number of same characters next to each other.

The only thing left to do for you is to notice that the only difference between the first half-tree and the second is some spaces in front of the stars.

Also notice that the number of spaces is quite predictable, given the number of stars: the total width of spaces and stars is constant.

Comment: I already noticed that, but if i use space in the same loop as "*" then it will repeat 5 times (if i choose N=5), the "space + '*'" and still wont get the result

Comment: Then you can try not doing it in the same loop? Print some spaces, then print some stars.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give a condition in inner loop. you should run the inner loop from 1 to n and print a `" "`(space) if j is less then i else print `'*'`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1 ; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if(j < i)
            putchar(' ');
        else
            putchar('*');

    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate!